# Retrieving top and left offset of a div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, position, offset

To get the top and left of the current div onclick have this.

```
<div class="channel" onclick="highlight_channel();">
    <p>Pax TV, 8am (Lima, Peru, in Spanish)</p>
</div>

function highlight_channel() {
    var highlight_top = $(this).position().top;
    var highlight_left = $(this).position().left;
    alert(highlight_top);
    var clear_highlight = document.getElementById("highlight");
    clear_highlight.parentElement.removeChild(clear_highlight); 
    $("#page").append('<div id="highlight" class="channel selected" style="top:'+highlight_top+'left='+highlight_left+'></div>');
}
```

This doesn't seem to get the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the jQuery click method if you are already using jQuery:

```
$('.channel').click(function() {
    var highlight_top = $(this).position().top;
    var highlight_left = $(this).position().left;
    alert(highlight_top);
    var clear_highlight = document.getElementById("highlight");
    clear_highlight.parentElement.removeChild(clear_highlight); 
    $("#page").append('<div id="highlight" class="channel selected" style="top:'+highlight_top+'left='+highlight_left+'></div>');

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZbnZ9/

Comment: The jquery click function was the right way.  However, for what I needed I had to simplify the function to be only `$('.channel').removeClass("selected"); $(this).addClass("selected");`.  This does the trick to highlight the clicked div. I put script tags right after the divs to be highlighted and this works.  Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qeXZV/.

Answer (score 1):

Try [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead of position().

Comment: Is offset() the right function whenever the result is to be used to set the top, left of an element?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function highlight_channel() {
    offs = $(this).offset(); // <-- caching for better performance.
    var highlight_top = offs.top;
    var highlight_left = offs.left;
    alert(highlight_top);
    $("#highlight").replaceWith('<div id="highlight" class="channel selected" style="top:'+highlight_top+'left='+highlight_left+'></div>'); // <-- replacing #highlight the jQuery way
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with the answer about the jquery .click function.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **" ; "** i think.

```
$("#page").append('<div id="highlight" class="channel selected" style="top:'+highlight_top+'; left='+highlight_left+'; ></div>');
```

Good luck.

Comment: OK.  These were needed in the style specifications.  But the problem was that I wasn't calling the function at the right place.